# winapi how to upload an image with an alpha channel?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I need to upload a PNG image. In the old project, I did this using drectx CreateDecoderFromFilename, but the code turned out to be too voluminous, I don’t want to bloat the project too much just to load an image. Are there relatively simple methods for downloading images with an alpha channel via Winapi, GDI+ or perhaps directx

Comment: upload and download to what? Do you mean draw? Or decode? How about libpng?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry, the problem is with the translator. I need to upload it to HBITMAP from my computer.